# My solr admin web page didn't appear normally

Tags: solr

I begin to study the Solr the last day. When I first install the Solr into my computer and start it, its function as well as Solr Admin webpages are all normally just like others.
But the second time I start the Solr,the Solr Admin didn't appear normally(see the photos). I spend much time to find、search and ask others, but I can't solve it yet.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFdNW.png)

Comment: Check your solr log to see what happened.

Comment: That seems to be a missing Solr-server behind the scenes, as there's no content actually being rendered in the frontend. Use the "network" tab in your browsers debugging tools to see what result your browser gets from Solr when its trying to open an URL and check the Solr log to see if Solr is available.

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly the right symptoms, but one of the common issues is when you start Solr with a **bin/solr start -e examplename** the first time and **bin/solr start** the second time. Using an example creates a directory in a different location, but the second start is using default location (under server) and does not see the same thing.

The solution is to use **bin/solr start -s path** version of the command. [A blog post](http://blog.outerthoughts.com/2015/11/oh-solr-home-where-art-thou/) has more details.